# htaccess RewriteRule - Removing '/' From The URL Causes Request To Display In URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a little problem concerning .htaccess.

The problem lies more in aesthetics than functionality. 
I have a very small htaccess file which contains the following, and nothing more:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\/\-]*)$ index.php?request=$1 [QSA]
```

This sends any requests to index.php, parsing in the URI. I then manipulate/read the URI to get the relevant file.

An example URL would be this:
http://localhost/domain/fixtures/2015/

Now, if I was to remove the end '/', and hit enter, the URL would change to:
http://localhost/domain/fixtures/2015/?request=fixtures/2015

I have tried adding a '/' to the rewrite but it does nothing.
I have searched across Google to no avail. (Bearing in mind some of my searches went along the lines of, "/ added to url htaccess rewrite")

The main reason I want to get this sorted is because it doesn't look pretty, but also because it creates duplicate content (i.e. you can get to the same page from both URL), which is not good for SEO.

Any direction I can be pointed in is a great help.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am reading this right, you want external URLs in this form:

```
http://localhost/domain/fixtures/2015/
```

And NOT this form:

```
http://localhost/domain/fixtures/2015
```

In order to achieve this, you need to use a redirect to let the remote
client know that the latter form is not valid, e.g.,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule .* %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

If you are also serving static content, you might want this as well:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

So, the full recipe including your PHP content generator:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\/\-]*)$ index.php?request=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you but this doesn't seem to do anything. I think the easiest way to do this is to just redirect any urls without the trailing slash to the same url with it. I just don't want the ".../?request=*" in the url...

Comment: I must not be understanding what you are asking for. First, the above code definitely redirects any URL without a trailing slash to the same URL with a trailing slash. Second, it seems nonsensical to say that you want all URLs to have a trailing slash, but you don't want them to end with slash. I can only surmise that I have completely misunderstood your original post.

Comment: No, you've understood perfectly fine. The code simply doesn't seem to have any impact at all. Maybe it's because it adds the "?request=fixtures" before htaccess is involved. I don't think I mentioned in the question (not sure why, now I look back) that the URL in the address bar is changed to "http://localhost/domain/fixtures/?request=fixtures", when I go to "http://localhost/domain/fixtures". This doesn't happen when I try to visit "http://localhost/domain/fixtures/", however.

Comment: Hi again, I have just tried going to the URL without the trailing slash on a different PC and it has redirected to the same URL with it. So, I guess it has worked! Maybe there was some kind of caching going on on my PC (although I done many hard refreshes and I'm pretty sure .htaccess isn't downloaded to the client anyway). Thank you very much for you response

Comment: Correct, .htaccess is not intended to be downloaded to the browser. Note that mod_rewrite has differences when used in the context of the server config versus an .htaccess. Best.